# Android.Gradle: How extract equal code from buildTypes?

Tags: android, gradle

My app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 80
        versionName "1.1.80"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="app/emails.txt"
        }
        debug {
            initWith(debug)
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="app/emails.txt"
        }
        dev {
            initWith(debug)
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="app/emails.txt"
        }
    }   
}
```

As you can see in every buildType has equal code:

```
 ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
 ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="app/emails.txt"
```

I want to do this code in some **ONE** place (extract from all buildTypes).
How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
buildTypes {
    base {
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
        ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="app/emails.txt"
    }
    release.initWith(buildTypes.base)
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    debug.initWith(buildTypes.base)
    debug {
    }
    dev_no_verification.initWith(buildTypes.base)
    dev_no_verification {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without create new buildType (base) ?

Comment: I don't know. I always use this method. Works like a charm. And intuitive because class extension widely used in all object-oriented languages

Comment: @user8542613 if it helps and you didn't find out other solution then please mark my answer as accepted. Or if you find other better solution answer it yourself and accept your answer